# Wordpress adding additional classes to navigation for Safari location.href and optimisation issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, wordpress, ipad

Hi I wrote this very simple piece of code to add some decoration to the top navigation in a wordpress theme based on the Url, and add in extra classes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var ispost = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("Page") > -1 && ispost ) 
    {

$( "nav ul li:contains('Page')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" ).addClass('current-menu-item current_page_item  active');
    }
});
</script>
```

This has resulted in two issues:
a) Optimisation / efficiency particularly in adding decoration to the element it effects (Javascript slow to load).
b) Safari on ipad / ios losing the classes 'current-menu-item current_page_item  active' that should be added to wordpress underlying navigation and decoration.

Noddy stuff to you guys. But my question is how do i get the code optimised and make safari have the added class? Where am i going wrong? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Please don't put everything in bold. It makes it more difficult to read and increases the likelihood that the question will be ignored.

Comment: Also, don't pollute your title with keywords. That's what tags are for.

Comment: i dont see how it affects downloading anything? But if you want optimization = php + cache result...that will work for all platforms

Comment: Download? Yes slight delay on element having styling added to it which i notice others don't.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you don't need JavaScript for this, this can be done in just CSS.

WordPress adds classes to the `body` element, so if you're looking for one specific page, get the ID of that page and use this CSS:

```
.page-1234 nav ul li:contains('Page') {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

As for the `addClass`-method, you should really be doing this in PHP, not JS.

Comment: That's great emil! but sadly it needs the conditional to identify the page as a post that specific to that page hierarchy only! So a) the page stands alone with its own styling b) if a post belongs to that page hierarchy then its styled in a similar way! But the current wordpress navigation i'm using dosen't allow for posts to be associated with a specific page. Hence the conditional code and asking for advice!